# TYPEORM setting fk in a 1:m / m:1

Tags: typescript, mariadb, typeorm

I have a table that looks like this

```
Table: hobbies
----------------------------------------
id | name
----------------------------------------
1  | chess
2  | skydiving
________________________________________
```

and then whenever someone is registering and adds a hobby (they can only have one hobby for simplicity sake and to make sure that this isn't a M:M)

```
Table: Users
------------------
id|   name    | hobbyId
------------------
1 |Christian  | NULL
```

here is how I implemented it:

```js
export async function addNewUser(userData: UserInformation): ServerReponse {
// userData = { name: "john", hobby: "skydiving" }
const hobbyRepo = getManager().getRepository('hobbies');
const hobbyId = await hobbyRepository.findOne({name: userData.hobby}) // hobbyId = { id: 2, name 'skydiving' }
const user = new User();
user.name = userData.name
user.hobby = hobbyId //user.hobby is underlined in red*
  try {
    await getManager().save(user);
  } catch(e){} //no error
```

the error for user.hobby I get is `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Specialty': id, name, membersts(2739)`

### entities: User

```js
@Entity('users')
export class User {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column()
  public name: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => Hobby, specialty => specialty.members)
  public hobby: Hobby;
}
```

### entity: Hobby

```js
@Entity('hobbies')
export class Hobby {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  public id: number;

  @Column()
  public name: string;

  @OneToMany(type => User, user => user.hobby)
  public members: User[];
}
```

with typeorm how would I assign the foreign key from a populated table?
thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So the error came because inside the `Hobby` class I had `members` as required. I am not 100% if this is a good idea or not, but, I made it optional as such:

```js
@OneToMany(type => User, user => user.specialy)
@JoinColomn()
public members?: User[] | User | null;
```

also in the model.ts file I have it now as:

```js
const hobbyFk = await hobbyRepository.findOne({name: userData.hobby});
user.name = userData.name;
user.hobby = hobbyFk as HobbyInterface; //HobbyInterface is one I created.
with that above I was able to correctly set the fk.
```

Hopefully this will help anyone else in the future.